# syntax error T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM!

Tags: php, javascript

buy.php:

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post">
<?php foreach($product['varieties'] as $variety): ?>
    <input style="width:10px; margin-left:9px; " name="price[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $variety['price'] . '_' . $variety['size']; ?>"  />';
<?php end foreach; ?>
</form>
```

cart.php:

```
list($aDoor, size)  = split('_', $_POST['price']); // line 207

if(empty($aDoor)) 
{
  echo("You didn't select any buildings.");
} 
else 
{
  echo "Sum of vlues = ".array_sum($aDoor);
}
```

In cart.php there is the following syntax error:

> syntax error, unexpected ')',
>   expecting T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in
>   store/cart.php on line 207

I am expecting in cart.php to receive the two index values size and price independetly so I can use it and CSS it where ever i want. I am expecting that with the function list() and split() the variables variety and $aDoor with the price value will able to separate this two variables to be use wherever I want in cart.php

Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@konforce can you see at the begining where you have set up the variable $aDoor and $size as arrays?

```
$aDoor = array();
$size = array();
```

Well now I am adding another index  value that is not an array it is an string

```
<input style="width:10px; margin-left:9px; " name="price[]" type="checkbox" value="' . $variety['price']. '_'. $variety['variety'] '_'. $product['name'].'"  />
```

you see the '. $product['name'].' well how can I receive it in cart.php 
in cart.php you have done the script as below but those are for arrays this time this one is not an array and I am seding it through the same form input.

```
$aDoor = array();
$size = array();

foreach ($_POST['price'] as $p)
{
  list($a, $b) = explode('_', $p);
  $aDoor[] = $a;
  $size[] = $b;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Missing a `$`:

`list($aDoor, $size)  = split('_', $_POST['price']); // line 207`

I think you are trying to do something like:

```
<?php
$aDoor = array();
$size = array();

foreach ($_POST['price'] as $p)
{
  list($a, $b) = explode('_', $p);
  $aDoor[] = $a;
  $size[] = $b;
}

if(empty($aDoor)) 
{
  echo("You didn't select any buildings.");
} 
else 
{
  echo "Sum of vlues = ".array_sum($aDoor);
}

?>
```

Comment: Yepp is missing the dolar sign

Comment: This seem to be ok to use
list($aDoor, $size) = split('_', $_POST['price']);

But how can I $size is a string and $aDoor are numbers 

to sum the numbers I can easly do by 

echo "Sum of vlues = ".array_sum($aDoor);

But how can I list the string inside of $size?

foreach($size as $variety) {
echo '<div>'.$variety['size']. '</div>
}

I have tried the above code to receive and echo the content of this varieble but it has print or display anything can any body help me on this? 

Thank you, Don't know that much of php

Comment: I've added an example as best as I can interpret your problem.

Comment: check my own answer below for a comment

Answer (score 2):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118755/questions-every-good-php-developer-should-be-able-to-answer/2118987#2118987) for a good primer. And Google is your friend :)

Answer (score 0):

It's Hebrew. It means twice colon. It also happens when you miss the $, like you have.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator#PHP

Comment: Ah double colon, if only they translated that phrase instead.

Comment: Yeh they should have. It's been in since PHP3. PHP: get things done... despite inconsistencies, etc.

Answer (score 0):

@Konforce I test your script and it works good.

Sorry I don't know what I was saying but I have to work it like this to list $size and prices $aDoor with the total below. I just have to style it now.

```
<?php
list($aDoor, $size) = split('_', $_POST['price']);
$aDoor = array();
$size = array();

foreach ($_POST['price'] as $p)
{
  list($a, $b) = explode('_', $p);
  $aDoor[] = $a;
  $size[] = $b;
}

   if(empty($aDoor)) 
{
  echo("You didn't select any buildings.");
} 
else 
{
   $V = count($size);

for($i=0; $i < $V; $i++)
    {

      echo($size[$i] . " ");
    } 
     $A = count($aDoor);
 for($i=0; $i < $A; $i++)
    {

      echo($aDoor[$i] . " ");
    }


  echo "Sum of vlues = ".array_sum($aDoor);
}
?>
```